# How to use WSAdmin to analyze Heap Dump files (.dmp)

Tags: wsadmin

I have a .dmp file of a WAS machine.. How can I use WSAdmin.sh to analyze the heap dump?

There are not many resources on this..

Answer (score 0):

WSAdmin is only for WAS administrative operations and does not provide any tooling to perform dump analysis, at least that I'm aware of.

I think what you're looking for is something like the Eclipse Memory Analyzer Tool (MAT), which can be found [here](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/).  It's specifically designed for processing and analyzing Java dump files.